# JavaScript - UTC date to milliseconds using moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to convert an UTC date to millis since UNIX epoch.

For this, I am doing the following:

```js
const date = new Date(); // local date
const utc = moment().utc(date); // UTC date
const utcMillis = utc.valueOf(); // Millis since UNIX epoch
```

Currently, I live in Spain (UTC + 2), and I have noticed that

`date.getTime() === moment().utc(date).valueOf()`

Why?

*Note: you can test this online [here](http://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/rLjQx/)*

Comment: The current ECMAScript *time value* (i.e. millisecond offset from 1 Jan 1970 UTC) is given by `Date.now()`, no need for a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> const date = new Date(); // local date
> ```

There is (currently) no such thing as a "local date" in ECMAScript. **All** *Date* instances are just an offset from the ECMAScript epoch, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, which is a fairly common epoch in programming.

> ```
> const utc = moment().utc(date); // UTC date
> ```

The *utc* method sets a moment object into UTC mode, so all *get* and *set* methods use their UTC variants. In this instance, a new *moment* object will be created after calling *getTime* (or maybe *valueOf*, the result is identical) on *date*. And since that time value is UTC already, utc mode has no effect on the outcome.

If you just want the current time value (i.e. millisecond offset from the ECMAScript epoch), then `Date.now()` does exactly that (allowing for system clock accuracy) without a library or jumping through hoops. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to the answers, quotes from the official documentation:

ECMAScript [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds since the [ECMAScript epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#the_ecmascript_epoch_and_timestamps).

ECMAScript [`Date.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf#description)

> The valueOf() method returns the primitive value of a Date object as a number data type, the number of milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC.
> This method is functionally equivalent to the Date.prototype.getTime() method.

MomentJS [`moment().valueOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/);

> moment#valueOf simply outputs the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch, just like Date#valueOf

All three are effectively return milliseconds elapsed since the unix epoch. And this value has **nothing to do** with current timezone or offset associated with the date object.

---

P.S. Upgrade to [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetime).

Comment: If I do not understand bad... new Date() creates a UTC+0 date and records the timezone offset. Then, depending on the implementation, when we do console.log() (toString(), toLocaleString()), we get the date as a local date string. But, what happens with valueOf()? When you say "returns the primitive value of a Date object as a number" do you mean that it does not consider the offset? That it only considers the UTC+0 date, right?

Comment: The thing about JS dates is that they really store a number internally. That number is unix epoch milliseconds. Another thing a date implementation may (or may not) store is an offset, (like +millis or -millis). So when you create a date (and do not specify an offset/zone) it stores the system (operating system) offset. From these two properties the date methods compute all the fancy or localized outputs.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what the timezone of a date is as it only represents a specific point in time. Given that all dates/times are based on the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z then it makes sense that no matter what you do, so long as 2 dates represent the same moment in time then their underlying values should also be the same.

Answer (score 0):

`Date()` doesn't value to local date and time, but values to UTC time instead. Check the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

So, it makes total sense for both values to be equal.